# My JSONObjectWithData is null

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, iphone, json

I have a problem with my JSON who send me a null value.

I think it's not a problem with my webservice in PhP because my colleague who is a expert in PhP doesn't see any error

Just below my Obj-C code

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);

        dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
            NSData *result = self.envoyerLaDemande;
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                id strResult=nil;

                strResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:nil];

                NSLog(@"strResult: %@", strResult);

                NSString* boolOk=[strResult objectForKey:@"result"];
                NSLog(@"BoolOk: %@", boolOk);
```

And there is the PHP script

```
$data = array();

if(condition == 1)
{
$data["result"] = "ok";
}
else
{
$data["result"] = "error";
}
$data["result"] = "coucou";
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

And the methode envoyerLaDemande

```
-(NSData*)envoyerLaDemande{


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mywebsite.com.com/App/V2/mailTo.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSString* requestFields;


requestFields = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"agence=%@&", nomAgence];

request.HTTPBody = requestData;
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error == nil && response.statusCode == 200) {
} else {
}
return responseData;

}
```

Comment: What does `self.envoyerLaDemande` look like?

Comment: @Batman please provide some more info.

Comment: @Rick self.envoyerLaDemande is my method when I call the webservice, I edit my post

Comment: @Batman use chrome add on postman to confirm that your service works properly and  use  NSURLConnectionDataDelegate method(didReceiveData ,didFailWithError ) , by breakpoints see the flow.

Comment: @learner: I try to replace post value with a value, the service work ;)

Comment: @Batman k, problem solved.

Comment: @learner No the problem isn't solved yet. The problem isn't the service...

Comment: @Batman if problem isn't solve then a suggestion please use AFnetworking http://afnetworking.com

Comment: Pls give the log of error or response.

Comment: add these [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];\

Comment: @amar: "strResult: (null) BoolOk: (null)"

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing two `dispacth_async`.

In the first one, you're telling the OS "Perform this code in the background", this will start loading the request in the background. However, immediately following that code you're telling the OS to perform a piece of code on the main thread. This piece of code accesses the `result` variable which hasn't been set yet because it's still being loaded in the background.

If you insist on using these dispatches, simply removing the dispatch back to the main queue should work. However, consider looking into [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html) or at the very least use the method [`sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:) on your `NSURLConnection`.

This code should work in your current scenario.

```
dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("downloader", NULL);

dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
    NSData *result = self.envoyerLaDemande;
    id strResult=nil;
    strResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"strResult: %@", strResult);
    NSString* boolOk=[strResult objectForKey:@"result"];
    NSLog(@"BoolOk: %@", boolOk);
}
```

EDIT:

Instead of simply ignoring the `error` and `response` objects, use them to diagnose the problem:

```
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
if (error == nil && response.statusCode == 200) {
    return responseData;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error. Status code: %d Error message: %@", response.statusCode, error.localizedDescription);
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work, the problem is still the same

Comment: Is `result` also nil? If so then the issue is probably in the communication to the server.

Comment: Yes the result is also nil. Communication with the server ? Unless the action i want the webservice doing, is good, but it don't send me the return value

Comment: Look at the documentation for sendSynchronousRequest. It says `Returns nil if a connection could not be created or if the download fails.`. So there is some problem with the download. I suggest looking at the `error` and `response` objects instead of simply ignoring them.

Comment: I put the code you wrote but i don't have any nslog concerning error, it just send me the responseData ;)

Comment: But it's still `nil`?

Comment: Yes. strResult: (null) BoolOk: (null)